# How to start a Task on the current thread (force inlining)

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

Here's the situation:
I have a computation pipeline, in a WPF application, which is full of small nodes that makes different calculations.  It is in fact a tree of those nodes which computations depends on the results of other nodes' computations.  Each node, when its dependencies changes, will trigger a recomputation by starting a task. So if I have a 1000 nodes in my graph. When one of the nodes changes at the bottom of the tree, it could happen that all the nodes need to recompute, each starting a task and waiting for the results of its child nodes to complete.

Symptoms: 
In certain situations, the computation pipeline seems to be "hanging" and taking a very long time to do simple calculation (normally would take less than a second, but could take from 30 seconds to 15 minutes)
By profiling, I noticed that the CPU is quite available, and that all the threads are simply waiting for the results of the child nodes. No one is doing calculation when having a breakpoint.

In my limited knowledge of the ThreadPool and TaskScheduler, is seems that the tasks that would be doing work are just far away in the queue, and thus everyone is just waiting.  Doesn't look like a deadlock, since it will resume at some point.
I guess I need to start less tasks, or to boost the ThreadPool's number of min thread to like 400 and then the problem disappears (but I prefer obviously the first solution)

Here's a quick glance on how I request the node's result (not actual code, since mine is bigger with thread safety and basic plumbing).

```
public T GetOrComputeValue()
{
    return GetOrComputeValueAsync().Result;
}

public Task<T> GetOrComputeValueAsync()
{
     // If we are not flagged as dirty, then we can return the last 
     // computation-task, which is either waiting to be started yet, 
     // still busy computing or might already have finished long ago. 
     if (!IsDirty && (_computationTask != null))
         return _pendingRecomputationTask ?? _computationTask;

     IsDirty = false;
     _computationTask = Task.Run( _computationFunc);
 }
```

So notice that a synchronous call will just call the Async version, which starts a new Task and wait for the result.  We made it like this so that if we have a synchronous "Get" call, followed by an Async call (before the sync call finished), we want to return the Synchronous Task's result.

The basic usage is from the UI Thread, we call the Async version of the top Computation Nodes (very few calls) and those nodes, in Tasks, will call the Synchronous version.

So, the origin of my question:
- Let's say a node's Task is already in a different thread than the UI thread, and it requests the result of a child node, can I ask that this child's task be inlined in the current thread instead of scheduling it?  Thus reducing the number of tasks sent to the TaskScheduler?

Or any other ideas?
Or I'm missing the point completely?!

Comment: Your basic problem is that you've created a `XXXAsync` method that isn't really asynchronous. You shouldn't use `Task.Run` like this :) Instead, just publish the synchronous version, and if you want to run it on a different thread, use `Task.Run`. The whole point is that while doing a true asynchronous operation (e.g. socket I/O), you're not actually using any threads (except for a short period during the callback).

Comment: And to expand a bit, given your symptoms, it is indeed likely you *do* in fact have a deadlock. The fact that eventually the thread pool grows large enough isn't really a solution - there's no point in having more threads than CPU cores (+ HT etc.). You need to redesign the multi-threading to work properly, rather than brute-forcing it through adding more threads. Not to mention that if you're also calling `GetOrComputeValueAsync` from a non-UI thread, you're bound to get issues even with those `IsDirty` checks and assignments etc. Multi-threading is rather hard to do reliably :)

Comment: I would recommend using `async` and `await` to avoid blocking threads.  This looks mighty synchronous to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that you are sending allot of tasks to the scheduler is not the problem, the problem is that you are (if I understand your scenario correctly) letting asynchronous code block synchronously to wait for the result of another asynchronous call, which in fact could cause a deadlock if your thread pool gets depleted.

My recommendation would be to make `_computationFunc` be of type `Func<Task<T>>` and it would immediately eliminate the need to call the synchronous `GetOrComputeValue` within a child node. If the child (leaf) node has no need to be an asynchronous calculation you could simple return its result with [`Task.FromResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194922(v=vs.110).aspx)

I would also suggest you use the `async` and `await` coding pattern to make your life much easier.

**EDIT:**
Regarding to your question about inlining the tasks on the current thread: in my opinion you should not be needing to if you follow my suggestion. But in order to inline a task would require [writing your own task scheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee789351(v=vs.110).aspx), but even then you will only be able to inline tasks that are not executing already (you cannot inline something that is already running)

Comment: I'd go a step further than Francois and recommend using TPL Dataflow blocks.  You have a lot of different calculations that could process in parallel and then need to line up again at some point in the tree.  TPL dataflow offers join blocks, broadcast blocks, batch blocks, etc which would make what you are doing a lot easier.  Asyn/await doesn't allow for much splitting.  You could also create a task factory to execute multiple tasks and add a continuewhenall to resync the multiple operation result set

Comment: Dataflow introduction: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/09/introduction-to-dataflow-part-1.html

Comment: TaskFactory continuewhenall: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321473%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: TPL Datflow joinblock: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228610%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @Francois Superb understanding!! Simple solution! Yes my major flaw that I forgot was (if I understand correctly) that Task.Result blocks without releasing the thread for other tasks.  I was already using "async await" when consuming my Nodes. Now the computation function itself (since it's now Func<Task<T>>) are also using "async await". Since the "waiting" is outside, then I don't have any "Task.Run" in my node's code.  I won't need inlining any Task (and thus not needing to implement a Task Scheduler)